# CSS color ignored by Safari

Tags: css, colors, safari

For some reason, Safari on OSX and iOS is ignoring color attribute on my buttons. Buttons are inside a pop-up modal, if that may change anything.

Please check the screenshots attached. First one displays active CSS rules, second one displays computed styles. It's obvious, that active rule for color attribute is #fff, but computed is somewhat blackish - inherited from the body color.

I suppose I could try and manually set the -webkit-text-fill-color to whatever value I desire, but question is - why is the color attribute ignored and computed/displayed wrongly in the first place?

**EDIT:**
I've come to realize, that colors for text are not ignored on just the buttons, but in many other places as well. Text inside some div's, spans as well, even input placeholders. All text colors are inherited from the body element.
All other browsers are fine, even on OSX/iOS.
I'm confused...

Actual css styles:

[image: Actual css styles]

Computed styles:

[image: Computed styles]

P.S. sorry for image quality - screenshots taken from Browserstack, as I don't own a Mac.

Please share your thoughts and ideas - what am I missing here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please add this styles for button or input[type="submit"]

**css**

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```